# c# socket client multiple BeginSend() don't arrive to server

Tags: java, c#, sockets, tcp, client-server

I'm using unity engine for client. I tested below code[method1]:

```
//connect to server
//unity gameobject c# client code

bool ConnectToServer() {
    try { 
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 
        socket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), serverPort); 
        socket.Blocking = true;
        AsyncObject ao = new AsyncObject(1024); 
        ao.WorkingSocket = socket; 
        receiveHandler = new AsyncCallback(OnReceive); 
        socket.BeginReceive(ao.Buffer, 0, ao.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, receiveHandler, ao); 
        return true;
    } 
    catch(SocketException e) { 
        Debug.Log(e.Message); 
        return false;
    } 
}

private void update() {
    //when keyboard is pressed
    socket.send(bytebuffer);
    socket.send(bytebuffer);
    socket.send(bytebuffer);
    socket.send(bytebuffer);
}
```

I found that my java server(using ServerSocketChannel and Selector) get only one data(bytebuffer) not four. So I tried other code using Stack[method2]:

```
Stack<byte[]> outDatas;
IAsyncResult res;
bool isSending = false;

void update() {
    if(outDatas.Count > 0 && res.IsComplete && isSending == false) {
        byte[] outData = outDatas.Pop();
        isSending = true;
        res = socket.BeginSend(outData, 0, outData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(onSendEnd), null);
    }
}

void onEndSend(IAsyncResult ar) {
        socket.EndSend(ar);
        isSending = false;
}

//use this function instead of socket.send
public void SendRequest(byte[] data) {
        outDatas.Push(data);
}
```

But the server got only one data, not four. This makes data leak out for my game. Why does [method2] does not work as I intended and How can I get work as I intended?

java server update code:

```
public void update(int tick) {
    selector.selectNow();
    iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
        if(key.isAcceptable()) {
            SocketChannel clientSocket = ((ServerSocketChannel)key.channel()).accept();
            clientSocket.configureBlocking(false);
            clientSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, user);
        }
        else if(key.isReadable()) {
            SocketChannel clientSocket = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
            inputBuffer.clear();
            int result = clientSocket.read(inputBuffer);
            handleInput((User)key.attachment());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the network traffic to eliminate the case that you are sending but not receiving properly. 

https://www.wireshark.org/

Then you will know where to focus, sender or receiver.

Comment: Data are streamed over a socket. If the client writes 4 times quickly, the server may receive all the data in a single packet.

Comment: @Olivier I checked the received byte length from server and it was 4 times than I exprected. Wow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the input byte length in server and it was 4 time than I expected. As @Olivier said in the comment, Server recieved datas in one packet.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.